# .htaccess redirect subdomain to php file without URL change in browser

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

help me please.

I have several php files in root

```
domain.com/dog.php
domain.com/cat.php
...
```

When user go to dog.domain.com i need to show domain.com/dog.php but keep dog.domain.com in browser URL

I already have this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com$
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/%1.php [L]
```

It works fine and show domain.com/dog.php content when I type dog.domain.com, but now it changes URL in browser to domain.com/dog.php

How to solve it?

P.S. Wildcard DNS record turned ON (already catch all subdomains *.domain.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *.domain.com is defined within the same vhost you have to use a relative RewriteRule there: `RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1.php [L]`). If not, you have to replace `[L]` by `[P]` and make sure that you have mod_proxy loaded. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Last but not least, you might want to update your `RewriteCond` to be case insensitive: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com$ [NC]`

Comment: `If *.domain.com is defined within the same vhost it should work as you described`. **No**. It should be `RewriteRule .* /%1.php [L]`. Otherwise, even with `L` flag, you'll get an external redirect because of `http://`

Comment: According to the examples on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule (see second table for .htaccess) it should be an internal redirect...